# How to scale and position a SCNNode that has a SCNSkinner attached?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

Using SceneKit, I'm loading a [very simple `.dae` file](https://gist.github.com/mattbierner/31458e40ce3b372d10bf46c839c508df) consisting of a large cylinder with three associated bones. I want to scale the cylinder down and position it on the ground. Here's the code

```
public class MyNode: SCNNode {

    public convenience init() {
        self.init()

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "test.dae")

        let cylinder = (scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Cylinder", recursively: true))!

        let scale: Float = 0.1
        cylinder.scale = SCNVector3Make(scale, scale, scale)
        cylinder.position = SCNVector3(0, scale, 0)

        self.addChildNode(cylinder)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work; the cylinder is still huge when I view it. The only way I can get the code to work is to remove associated [`SCNSKinner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnskinner).

```
cylinder.skinner = nil
```

Why does this happen and how can I properly scale and position the model, bones and all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when a geometry is skinned it is driven by its skeleton. Which means that the transform of the skinned node is no longer used, it's the transforms of the bones that are important.

For this file `Armature` is the root of the skeleton. If you translate/scale this node instead of `Cylinder` you'll get what you want.

Comment: What happens if "Armature" have severely bones under it. How can you manipulate them separately

Comment: After I wrote comment here I found how to use animation which is designed in Blender. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099232/scnanimationplayer-seems-to-be-playing-only-small-part-of-animation-while-usin/62128572#62128572